# Rails - passing additional variables on .create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to put into practise using skinny controllers and fat models, however in order to do this I find myself needing to pass additional variables into the .create method.

So for example where I had:

```
@app =  App.new(app_params)

def app_params
  params.require(:app).permit( :name,  :description)
end
```

Now I want to also pass along say, a session held user_id, and a reference to a permission group. So hopefully something like the following pseudo code:

```
@app = App.create(app_params, session[:user_id], app_permission_id)
```

The user_id and app_permission_id would not be persisted but would be available I'd hope somewhere like in the after_create callback within the model, so I can then do some further work, for example creating a log entry of the creation, associated to the calling user.

I'm not so keen on just adding them in the form as hidden fields (to hide implementation from users). I think there is a possible approach using .merge? if that's the way, the I guess I pull them out using a virtual attribute.

Any advise on the best/cleanest approach would be much appreciated. I think I'd prefer to override the .create method somehow (but only in terms of the cleanest implementation from the controller side).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If you are app_params should always contain user_id and app_permission_id**

you should do it this way

```
def app_params
  params.require(:app).permit( :name,  :description).merge(user_id: session[:user_id], app_permission_id: app_permission_id)
end
```

**Else if it should not contain this all the time**

you should do it this way

```
app_params.merge(user_id: session[:user_id], app_permission_id: app_permission_id) #as mentioned by Vapire in his answer
```

Comment: OK, many thanks, I like the first way round (merging in the params method) as they are all required, and after some fiddling with FactoryGirl to get my testcases working, it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be possible with `merge`

```
def create
  @app = App.new(app_params.merge(user_id: session[:user_id], app_permission_id: app_permission_id))
end
```

Of course you'd need virtual attributes `user_id` and `app_permission_id` in your model.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530532/rails-4-insert-attribute-into-params).

Answer (score 1):

The two answers describing `.merge` are correct; let me explain why

--

**Params**

When processing your params at controller level, and handling with `strong_params`, Rails basically "passes" the data through to your model, like this:

```
"params" => {
   "app" => {
      "name" => "data",
      "description" => "data",
    }
}
```

This is what the typical `form_for` params object sends through to your controller. When you pick up the data through the `strong_params` method, you basically just "permit" the various pieces of data to pass through to the model.

Remember, `strong_params` are designed to help prevent `mass_assignment`, which means the method is designed to only send particular params through to your model.

--

**Fix**

If you want to append extra data to each model request - you'll have to use `merge`:

```
def app_params
   params.require(:app).permit(:name, :description).merge(user_id: session[:user_id], app_permission_id: app_permission_id) 
end
```