# Rails 4 - Change Params Before Save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form to create a new Task.  Inside the form, the user can select a Client that has been previously added using another form.  I'd like to give the user to add a new Client "on the fly".  Here is what I've tried so far.

In my view, I have a `collection_select` to display the current Clients.  I then use a little bit of jQuery to add a new element to this list "Add another...".  When this option is selected, the select menu is replaced with a text field where the user can enter a new Client's name:

```
<script>
  $("#task_client_id").append('<option value=999>Add another...</option>');
  $('select[name="task[client_id]"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "999") {
      $("#task_client_id").replaceWith('<input placeholder="Enter new client name" type="text" name="task[client_name]" id="task_client_name">');
    }
  });
</script>
```

This creates a new parameter called "client_name".  In my Task model, I added an `attr_accessor` for client_name so that it will not be an "Unknown Attribute".

Then in my controller, I have the following code:

```
  def create
    tp = task_params
    if tp[:client_name]
      c = Client.create(name: tp[:client_name])
      tp[:client_id] = c.id
    end
    if @task.save
      redirect_to new_task_task_detail_path(@task), notice: "Task created successfully!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Where `task_params` is the private method for strong parameters (that includes client_name).

The Client actually gets created thanks to the code, but the form still renders an error due to my validation on client_id which is not present in the params hash.

I was hoping that the part `tp[:client_id] = c.id` would add client_id to the params hash prior to calling `@task.save`, but it does not.  This is confirmed by adding a `fail` prior to calling `@task.save`.

How can I insert "client_id" into the params hash prior to saving it?  I have also tried merge following this: [Rails 4: Insert Attribute Into Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530532/rails-4-insert-attribute-into-params), but could not get that to work either.

Comment: Where are you defining `@task`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `client_id` to whatever object is validating for its existence. If `@task` requires a `client_id`, then assign `@task.client_id = c.id` prior to calling `@task.save`.

Comment: That works!  No idea why I didn't think of that :-).  Thanks!